# How create a Custom Listview with more than 2 items

Tags: android-listview, android-adapter, android-filter, android-textwatcher

i am trying to create a list view with more than 2 items i know is not difficult but I have a while trying and nothing ... 
Example
I want to show the code, name and price of a product. I used array adapter with 1 item and two item but I need 3... 
Can someone show me a sample code how I can do this?  Show 3 or more items in a row of a listview...
 Thanks

i know how to do this
[image]

i want to do this

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Perhaps you could give an example using ASCII art?

Comment: I have a list of products (inventory) I want to show a listview with the name of product, the price and barcode. But I only know how to show 2 items I the listview row. I use two_line_item and I want to know the way to use more than 2 line item... Do you understand? I have a bad English sorry.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words: can you draw a picture of what you want? Just a simple ASCII drawing would suffice. E.g., something like the drawing here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279761/how-to-change-column-width-on-each-row.

Answer (score 0):

Make a **ArrayList** of your desired model like you can make your 
`model.class`

and add items in it like

`String item1,item2,item3`

and pass this in `arraylist` and passing through `adapter`